# How can I specify openGL version in Vagrant Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, opengl, vagrant, kivy, sdl-2

I am currently trying to get the Python library Kivy working on an Ubuntu virtual machine (vagrant box  bento/ubuntu-16.04). I've managed to get the VM displaying windows using x11 and sdl2, and can even briefly launch a Kivy window. However, it then gives segmentation fault, and requires openGL version >= 2.0:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'1.4 (2.1.2 NVIDIA 375.26)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 1, 4
[CRITICAL] [GL          ] Minimum required OpenGL version (2.0) NOT found!
```

On the host machine the openGL configuration is:

```
>>glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 375.26
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.26
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 375.26
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions,
```

whilst on the VM the setup is:

```
>>glxinfo | grep version
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1.2 NVIDIA 375.26)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get the VM using the host openGL drivers, or know how to install an openGL version >= 2.0 on the VM?

Best,
Sam

Comment: It's not as simple as "installing" OpenGL. It requires hardware support, which in this case is a supported OS, newest guest additions and prayer. I don't think vagrant installs guest additions by default, so get into the machine and see if they're there.

Comment: Also voting to close because this is about how to use virtual machines to achieve hardware-accelerated graphics, and vagrant has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This is helpful information, I hadn't heard of guest additions or even the term hardware accelerated graphics.